# Calling C function which has omp task from Fortran

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, fortran, openmp

I'm working on a project which is coded in CUDA-Fortran now. The only compiler that can compile CUDA-Fortran is the Portland group's pgfortran compiler. But we have found a bug that the pgfortran compiler always serializes the OMP task directive. In easy word: OMP TASK is not paralleled when compiled with PGI's compiler while paralleled when compiled with GNU's compiler. We have report this to PGI and we are not sure that how long it will take to fix the bug. So now I'm trying to call a C function( more specifically a CUDA function) from the Fortran program( in testF.cuf ) and put the OMP task directive in the C function (in cuda.cu) because we know that gcc's omp task works fine.

testF.cuf:

```
external cfunction
...    
cfunction( foo )
```

cuda.cu

```
extern "C" function_(Foo * foo){

#pragma omp parallel
{
  ...
#pragma omp single
  {
     ...
#pragma omp task 
    {
      ...
    }
  }
 }
}
```

The result is that a Fortran program without any OMP directive in it can call the C function and the OMP task is parallel. But once we put any OMP stuff in the Fortran code or just put a -mp flag when compiling the Fortran code. The OMP task in the C file will act like they are in PGI's way: serialized. And if I change the OMP task to OMP parallel for the result will be correct again. This suggest that the pgfortran will link the OMP in C code into pgfortran's wrong way.

Here is my Makefile:

```
myFtoCU: cuda.o testF.o
   pgfortran cuda.o testF.o -o myFtoCU  -Mcuda=5.0  -lstdc++ -lgomp 
cuda.o: cuda.cu
   nvcc   -c cuda.cu -o cuda.o  -Xcompiler -fopenmp  -lgomp
testF.o: testF.cuf
   pgfortran -c testF.cuf -Mcuda=5.0 -lstdc++ -lgomp -mp
clean:  cuda.o testF.o myFtoCU
   rm cuda.o testF.o ./myFtoCU
```

I guess the problem is that when I link the cuda.o and testF.o together, the linker force the OMP in cuda.o act as the pgfortran's OMP task, which is wrong.

So are there anyone know that how can I link this two object correctly while keep the C( CUDA ) function more independently?

Comment: Those 2 compilers can use (and probably use) completely different OpenMP implementations.